# From where does the pentaho dashboards js files loaded in generatedContent html code

Tags: javascript, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I have created pentaho dashboards using Bi-server 5.3 CE.

When i open the dashboards,I can see some default scripts loaded for every dashboard. example:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  Dashboards.context = {
  "locale": "en_US",
  "params": {},
  "path": "/home/Dashboards_local/Operational_Metrics.wcdf",
  "queryData": {},
  "roles": [
    "Administrator",
    "Authenticated"
  ],
  "serverLocalDate": 1500462041870,
  "serverUTCDate": 1500442241870,
  "sessionAttributes": {},
  "sessionTimeout": 7200,
  "user": "admin"
}
Dashboards.initialStorage = {}
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
wcdfSettings = {
  "title": "Operational_Metrics",
  "author": "",
  "description": "Operational_Metrics_V1.2",
  "style": "Clean",
  "widgetName": "",
  "widget": false,
  "rendererType": "bootstrap",
  "widgetParameters": []
};
```

Can anyone tell me from where does this js scripts are loaded from.
Where does the template html located for the dashboards created in pentaho.